# HTML Table Problem: Static width with display:block and variuos text length

Tags: html, html-table, tr

actually i got a problem with the view of a table. I need a horizontal scrollbar in my `<td>`. For this i found here a solution:

```
<table style="min-width: 100%; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; border-collapse: collapse;" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
<tr class="list" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 5px;">
<td style="display: block; min-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; white-space: nowrap; overflow:auto;" colspan="2">
<?php echo user_view_explorer_form (); ?>
</td></tr> 
</table>
```

But now i got the problem, that some elements of the `<td>` are very short and some are very long. In case the elements are to short for a width:100%-view, the whole table only shows has the width of the longest element.

I cant find a solution where I can scroll in case of long elements but also got a "width:100%"-table in case of short elements.

Sorry for bad english. Thank you for your help. Stay healthy.

Picture shows you the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50SkE.png)

Comment: Brother can you care to elaborate a little more. I can't get the problem you are facing.

Comment: Please add your code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `display: block` to a `table` element (be it `table` or `td`)  *destroys*  the automatic formating as a table in HTML - it simply doesn't make sense to do that (you could as well work with `div`s then)

So erase all this `display: block` instances! To set the table to 100% width, simply use `width: 100%` on `table`

To limit the height of a `td` and make it scroll vertically, you could put a `div` *into*  that `td` and apply a fixed `height` to it. But all inside a working table structure without `display: block` on *any* table/tr/td element...

Comment: I know that, but I need a horizontal scrollbar for the long-text elements. And I just found a way to improve that with the `display: block`elemt in `<table>`...

Comment: please note the addition to my answer.

Comment: I know this.. but I need a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Have you tried `width: auto` and  `min-width: 100%` on the `table`?

Comment: Doesnt help. With your answer the div ranges in the document-list, when there are long-text elements.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood what you write here, I can offer you, try to wrapper element using for width configuration where you have problem on giving a width. If you write your all code here(including where you have problem) i may help you better than now :)